# ImGui use both 'enter' and numeric keypad 'enter' as ImGuiKey_Enter

Tags: c++, opengl

In imgui you can set the keycodes for later lookup, it looks like

```
io.KeyMap[ImGuiKey_Enter] = WXK_RETURN;
```

How could i do something like

```
io.KeyMap[ImGuiKey_Enter] = WXK_RETURN || WXK_NUMPAD_ENTER;
```

(this obvoiously does not work, just for explanation) so both 'enter' keys trigger an 'enter' action?

(By the way, can someone with sufficient karma open an imgui-tag? It is pretty popular.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

io.KeyMap[] is merely a indication of where to read the inside the io.KeysDown[] array, which is also something you've filled. So you could for example merge both keys values:

```
io.KeyMap[ImGuiKey_Enter] = WXK_RETURN;
io.KeysDown[WXK_RETURN] = my_wx_keys[WXK_RETURN] | my_wx_keys[WXK_NUMPAD_ENTER];
```